# How to use variable in table name in object_id statement in a while-loop in sql

Tags: sql, variables, while-loop

I need to erase a various number of tables which is depending on a while-loop. Everything in the loop works beside the interpretation of the object_id statement. My code looks like this:

```
declare @t int = 10
while @t <=11
begin
  if object_id('[a\b].rot@t'. 'U') is null
  drop table [a\b].rot@t
  set @t = @t + 1
end
```

This gives me an error messages as follows:
"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '@t'."

The error message refer to the "@t" within the if object_id statement.

I've tried different version of my if object_id statement similar to that in my example code without any luck. If I hard code the value the script works as expected.

The short loop interval is just for test and the short code is an example of the problem I encounter. Both the loop interval and the code is much longer and complex in reality.

Due to company rules I'm unable to provide source data, but I hope someone can help med solve how to get my "if object_id" statement to understand the variable in my table name. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the drop table statement into a text variable and execute the string EXEC DropTableVariable  So DropTableVariable =  string to drop table.  (wouldnt let me put the @ before DropTableVariable text

Comment: I coud'nt get it to work. I got a error message that said "The name 'drop table..." was unvalid? I also tried to create an temporary procedure, but there I run into the same problem as before. I can't get the table name to work. Can you help me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I dont know what SQL your using MSSQL or MYSQL, or other.

This syntax I am unfamiliar with what:  '[a\b].rot@t'  so I put a note below you may have to do that differently as I am not familiar with how that is working.

But syntax may be different but you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL varchar(MAX) = ''
declare @t int = 10
while @t <=11
begin
  if object_id('[a\b].rot@t'. 'U') is null

-- here instead of doing drop directly build out a string:

--drop table [a\b].rot@t  dont do this 
-- though I am not familar with this syntax of the @t in the string, so you may have to concat that with the drop table some other way
SET @DynamicSQL = 'drop table [a\b].rot@t'  
-- then execute the dynamic SQL variable
EXEC @DynamicSQL
  set @t = @t + 1
end
```

Comment: GREAT! Thanks allot. I run into some "detective work" with how to get my integer to work in the stringvariable. But thanks to your comment in your code I eventually managed to find the answer. Since I use MSSQL the solutions to the problems I run into from your code was that I needed () around the dynamic variable name in the exec statement and I needed to cast the integer to a varchar in the stringvariable as follows: set @DynamicSQL = 'drop table [a\b].rot' + cast(@t as varchar).